# How to evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why can it not evaluate this integral? Please help.

```
Integrate[Exp[-r^2]* r^2*Log[Exp[-r^2]* r^2*(2.5 - r^2)*(2.5 - r^2)], {r, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 9):

It's because it has no closed form, and the default numerical methods don't converge quite fast enough on it.

`NIntegrate` returns `-0.585566` given a higher-than-usual value of `MaxRecursion`:

```
NIntegrate[
 Exp[-r^2]*r^2*Log[Exp[-r^2]*r^2*(25/10 - r^2)*(25/10 - r^2)],
 {r, 0, 10},
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

Here's how to do it without specifying any `MaxRecursion`.

There is a problem at $\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$, where the `Log` expression becomes negative-infinite. Split the integral up into those two sections, and simplify the first one (on $\left[0, \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \right]$), which may be found explicitly to be:

```
(2*Sqrt[10]*(36 + 18*EulerGamma - 10*E^(5/2)*HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2}, {5/2, 5/2}, 
  -5/2] - 27*Log[5/2]) - 9*E^(5/2)*Sqrt[Pi]*(4*EulerGamma*Erf[Sqrt[5/2]] - 
3*Erf[Sqrt[5/2]]*(-1 + Log[25/4]) + 
2*Sqrt[10]*(-Derivative[0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric1F1Regularized][1/2, 3/2, -5/2] + 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric1F1Regularized][3/2, 3/2, -5/2])))/(72*E^(5/2))
```

with approximate value `-0.337658`.

(The expression is `Integrate[Exp[-r^2]*r^2*Log[Exp[-r^2]*r^2], {r, 0, Sqrt[5/2]}] + Integrate[2 Exp[-r^2]*r^2*Log[(25/10 - r^2)], {r, 0, Sqrt[5/2]}]`.)

Now for the second part:

```
Integrate[
 Exp[-r^2]*r^2*Log[Exp[-r^2]*r^2*(25/10 - r^2)*(25/10 - r^2)],
 {r, Sqrt[5/2], 10}]
```

Mathematica thinks this is approximately `-0.247907895`, though without a closed form; it doesn't need any options to `N` or `NIntegrate` to work this out.

Therefore the value of the original integral would seem to be `-0.585566`.

Comment: Note you can specify divisions at singularities like this: `NIntegrate[Exp[-r^2]*r^2*Log[Exp[-r^2]*r^2*(25/10 - r^2)*(25/10 - r^2)], {r, 0, Sqrt[5/2], 10}]`, with the division points in the iterator `{r, 0, Sqrt[5/2], 10}`.  (Converges quickly to your result.)

Comment: @melena, could I nudge you to accept this answer please, if it's all sorted? I don't like looking at my user page and seeing those horrible grey squares in the answers list :)

Comment: how can I do? Actually I don't understand Patrick what are you saying :(